# Camunda Tables not getting created on startup

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, camunda

I am trying to setup Camunda workflow engine along with Grails application. I am using Camunda plugin for grails but on application startup, application is not able to create Camunda tables. The database for our test instance is oracle. When I try to run the grails application in local with H2 in memory database, the camunda tables are getting created but as soon as I point my local application to test Oracle DB, it throws the below mentioned exception.

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Property.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.PropertyEntity.selectProperty-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.selectById(DbSqlSession.java:110)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectById(DbEntityManager.java:210)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.PropertyManager.findPropertyById(PropertyManager.java:29)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.HistoryLevelSetupCommand.checkStartupLockExists(HistoryLevelSetupCommand.java:107)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.HistoryLevelSetupCommand.execute(HistoryLevelSetupCommand.java:39)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.HistoryLevelSetupCommand.execute(HistoryLevelSetupCommand.java:31)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:110)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which Grails version? Which Camunda plugin version? Are tables created in oracle db? (`ORA-00942` might be thrown as a permission exception)

Comment: Grails 3.2.....Camunda 7.12.0.....No tables are not getting created automatically when application starts. I tried to configure mysql DB on my local....tables get created automatically in mysql ...I want the same with oracle i.e. test instance but it not happening.

Comment: Share your db config and which exactly dependencies are you using